# Why I am getting a single value instead of a JSON in Node.JS code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, node-mysql

I am trying to develop an AWS lambda function with Node.JS. I am actually building a REST API with AWS Lambda, API Gateway and AWS RDS(MySQL).  Please check the below code

```
var response;

exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {

    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "***",
        user: "***",
        password: "***",
        database: "aaaa",
        port: 3306
    });

    con.connect();

    try {
        conn.query('SELECT * from accounting_type', function (err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err);

            console.log(data);

            conn.close(function () {
                console.log('done');
            });

            response = {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': JSON.stringify({
                    data,
                })
            }

        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }

    return response;

};
```

In this code, the response I get is just `1`.

However, the output I need is this.

```
[
    {
        "idaccountingType": 1,
        "type": "credit"
    },
    {
        "idaccountingType": 2,
        "type": "debit"
    }
]
```

This is the first time I am using Node.JS, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the console.log(data) line dump out?

Comment: I hope those aren't your real AWS credentials.

Comment: `conn.query()` is asynchronous. You're not waiting for it before `return response;`

Comment: @Barmar: No. I made them up.

Comment: @Barmar: Thank you Barmar. Can you help me out with this? This is my first time on this subject.